# CMake unable to find boost_test

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

On OSX, I have installed Boost using `brew install boost`, and I'm trying to link as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(LinkBoost)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(LinkBoost
    desmond.cpp
    desmond.h
    integration.cpp
    integration.h
    main.cpp
    main.h
    utillity.cpp
    utillity.h)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.69.0_2")
set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.69.0" "1.69")

find_package(BoostCOMPONENTS filesystem system test REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(LinkBoost PUBLIC ".")

# adds include directories, definitions and link libraries
target_link_libraries(VelocityDispersion PUBLIC
        Boost::filesystem Boost::system Boost::test)
```

This however gives me:

```
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

Boost version: 1.69.0

Boost include path: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.69.0_2/include

Could not find the following Boost libraries:

      boost_test

Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
to the location of Boost.
```

Can anyone help me understand what is going wrong here? I feel like it's something obvious that I'm missing...

Comment: The Boost.Test framework has a few different [usage variants](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/usage_variants.html). Can you verify that the Boost.Test library was installed on your system, probably located along with the other `libboost_` Boost libraries, such as `libboost_system`, `libboost_filesystem`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working with something along the lines of:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(LinkBoost)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem unit_test_framework REQUIRED )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )
LINK_DIRECTORIES ( ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

add_executable(LinkBoost
    desmond.cpp
    desmond.h
    integration.cpp
    integration.h
    main.cpp
    main.h
    utillity.cpp
    utillity.h)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(LinkBoost LINK_PUBLIC
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY})
```

But I think a larger part of the problem was my fundamental understanding of how Boost Tests work - I would encourage anyone struggling here to read the documentation for Boost.